# Effectively change dimension of scipy.spare.csr_matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a function that takes a `csr_matrix` and does some calculations on it.

The behavior of these calculation requires the shape of this matrix to be specific (say `NxM`).

The input I send has less columns and the exact number of rows.

(e.g. it has shape=(A,B) where A < N and B == M)

For example: I have the object `x`

```
>>>x = csr_matrix([[1,2],[1,2]])
>>>x
(0, 0)  1
(0, 1)  2
(1, 0)  1
(1, 1)  2
>>>x.shape
(2, 2)
```

And a function `f`:

```
def f(csr_mat):
    """csr_mat.shape should be (2,3)"""
```

Then I want to do something on `x`, so it will become `y`:

```
>>>y = csr_matrix([[1,2,0],[1,2,0]])
>>>y
(0, 0)  1
(0, 1)  2
(1, 0)  1
(1, 1)  2
>>>y.shape
(2, 3)
```

In this example, `x` and `y` has the same none-zero values, but `y` has different shape. What I want is to efficiently 'extend' `x` to a new dimension, filling new columns with zeros. Namely, given `x` and `new_shape=(2,3)`, it should return `y`.
I already tried `reshape`:

```
x.reshape((2,3))
```

But then I got:

> NotImplementedError

My second option was just to create new `csr_matrix` with different shape:

```
z = csr_matrix(x,shape=(3,3))
```

But this fails as well:

> NotImplementedError: Reshaping not implemented for csr_matrix.

EDIT: using csc_matrix has brought the same errors.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: @talonmies using csc_matrix gave me the same errors. You have something specific in mind?

Comment: @talonmies I am trying to avoid creating a new object. this is NOT THE SAME QUESTION. (creating a new object will add 5 minutes to each run!)

Comment: The constructor contains an option to not copy data, which means there is little cost in constructing a new object from an existing object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the CSR format, the underlying `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` arrays for your desired `y` are identical to those of your `x` matrix. You can pass those to the `csr_matrix` constructor with a new `shape`:

```
y = csr_matrix((x.data, x.indices, x.indptr), shape=(2, 3))
```

Note that the constructor defaults to `copy=False`, so this will share the `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` between `x` and `y`. Some operations on `y` will be reflected in `x`. You can pass `copy=True` to make `x` and `y` independent of each other.

If you want to poke at the undocumented internals of `csr_matrix`, you can set the internal `_shape` attribute to make the `x` array have the shape you want:

```
x._shape = (2, 3)
```

There isn't really an advantage to doing it this way.

Comment: Since I have no problem extending the original object, Isn't there something more efficient than to create a new object?

Comment: @OBP: This shares the `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` between `x` and `y`; it's not an expensive operation.

Comment: OK then, I thought there is something even more simple